# Resolve url.html/comment-page-1 to url/comment-page-1 through htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Some days back, I have changes WordPress URL's to URL.html via .htaccess. I Know it was very smart move. As google crawled all tne pages, but there were too much 404 error in Webmaster Tools. After some days later I have removes .html from URL. but the real problem happens later.

Now my problem is:

I want to changes the **URL.html/comment-page-1** to **URL/comment-page-1** (default). I am not good with .htaccess. So please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this redirect rule **before other wordpress rules**:

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html/(.*)$ /$1/$2 [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks very much. It really helped, and now my problem is resolved..Can I ask one more .htaccess problem.

Comment: Yes sure you can definitely post a new problem.

Comment: I have tried. but it says you need 15 reputation point :(

Comment: Hello @anubhava please check my question [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25602943/resolve-website-page-pagination-through-htaccess[/link]