# Resolve Website Page Pagination through htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is my problem.

I want to resolve

- `Website.in/home-page/page/73/` to `Website.in/page/73/`
- `Website.in/home-page/page/74/` to `Website.in/page/74/`
- etc.

One more problem I'm getting is the following `Website.in/page-url/function.include-once`

I installes some WordPress plug-ins which I also deleted. But Google Webmastertool is showing lots of 404 errors.

My last question asked was here : [Resolve url.html/comment-page-1 to url/comment-page-1 through htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25598287/resolve-url-html-comment-page-1-to-url-comment-page-1-through-htaccess)

Comment: use `permalink option`

Comment: I am already checked that option. But it didn't resolve it. Some .htaccess code tweak can do.

Comment: Is `/home-page/` a directory?

Comment: Is the intent to delete `/home-page/` from all URLs?

Comment: @anubhava /home-page/ is not director. Did some tweaks. but now search engine is showing 404 error.. So i want to resolve this issue.

Comment: Ok posted an answer below, try it and let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use this rule as **your very first rule**:

```
RewriteRule ^home-page/(.+)$ /$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: That's nice, @anubhava!

Comment: can you please help me with another issue `Website.in/page-url/function.include-once`

Comment: I have used some crap wordpress plugin, but after uninstalling it, I am getting `website-page-url/function.include-once` so i want to remove that `function.include-once` from the end of URL. Thanks you @anubhava

Comment: You can add another redirect rule just below above: `RewriteRule ^page-url/(.+)$ /$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]`

Comment: `page-url` means all `HTTP URL` of my articles.. Can I use `[HOST_URI]` . the last comment didn't resolve it..

Comment: Ok try: `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/function\.include-once/?$ /$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]`

Comment: @anubhava is not redirecting. http://www.weeklyexam.in/2013/12/07/rpsc-ldc-grade-ii-january-2014-written-exam-syllabus-download/function.include-once

Comment: oh ok try this now: `RewriteRule ^(.+?)/function\.include-once/?$ /$1/ [L,NC,NE,R=301]`

Comment: thanks - it is working now. Resolved both my issues.Thanks @anubhava .

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^home-page/page/([^/]*)([/]?)$ /page/$1/ [L,QSA]
```

The `([/]?)` will match if the URL ends with a `/` **or** doesn't end with a `/`.

You can test it here: http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/

[image: Preview of the test]

[image: Preview of the test 2]

Comment: Please add */* at the end of URL.. I want to resolve **Website.in/home-page/page/73/** to **Website.in/page/73/**  Thanks.

Comment: Its not working at http://www.weeklyexam.in/home-page/page/94/ , the page is not redirecting. :(

Comment: Are there any other rewrite rules that may conflict?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^home-page/(.+)$ /$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]` by @anubhava has resolved it.